# call to undefined method dom element::dump_mem

Tags: php, wampserver

i used

```
 $xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
echo $xmlfile;
```

with

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
```

and get this

> **error: call to undefined method domelement::dump_mem**

Comment: dump_mem doesn't exist as a standard method for the PHP [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class; so I'm unsure why you'd expect it to work

Comment: see the documentation for valid methods: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: use var_dump instead!

Comment: i cannot find correct method instead of dump_mem()                        please help me to find answer.

Comment: var_dump does'nt work!!

Comment: perhaps the [saveHTML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) or [saveXML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) methods; but it depends what you actually want to do.... reading the docs for the available methods might help you

Comment: i used saveXML() and get my xml tree rigth;very thanks for your guid:-)